# {exp:comment:notification_links} not displaying anything

Tags: comments, subscriptions

I copied the example in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/#comment-notification-links-tag) to display

```
{exp:comment:notification_links}
    {if subscribed}
            <h5><a href="{unsubscribe_link}">Unsubscribe to comment notification for this entry.</a></h5>
    {if:else}
            <h5><a href="{subscribe_link}">Subscribe to comment notification for this entry.</a></h5>
    {/if}
{/exp:comment:notification_links}
```

However, nothing is outputted.

Is this supposed to be inside a {exp:comment:entries} or {exp:channel:entries} tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're logged out, you shouldn't see anything, so make sure you're logged in. Second, this tag needs to be on a single entry page and it will try to figure out your entry ID by:

- Checking to see if you used an `entry_id=` or `url_title=` parameter on the `{exp:comment:notification_links}` tag
- Checking the URI to see if the entry ID shows up there

So, if your entry id or URL title is **not** in the URI, you should be using the `entry_id=` or `url_title=` parameters.

Comment: I did not put in the entry_id parameter because it wasn't really specified in the example. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @arvinsim I'll make sure to clarify that in the documentation.